# Computing fibre products of schemes (not affine)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is clear how to compute the fiber product of two affine schemes. But Rhow can one compute the fiber product $X \times _{R} Spec(k[y])$ where $R$ is an integral domain, $X$ defined by the zero set of $f(x,y,z)$ in the projective plane (i.e. $X=Proj(R[x,y,z]/(f))$ ) and $y$ the generic point of $X$, $k[y]$ the residue field at $y$? Do I have to compute first the fiber product of an affine cover of $X$ and then glue? How can I do this concretely? Thanks for your help!

Comment: By "computing" this fibre product, what exactly do you mean? What kind of data constitutes a *computed* fibre product, as opposed to writing $X\times_R\mathrm{Spec}(k[y])$?

Comment: It means to write X×RSpec(k[y]). My idea was to consider the affine cover U0= {x≠0}∩X and so on and then glue. But I'm not sure how to do this concretely.

Comment: If "it means to write XxRSpec(k[y])", then I'd say you're done.

Comment: I find your notations quite confusing : $y$ is both an indeterminate and a generic point, k[y] is a field ?

Comment: Yes, that is really confusing. Let $\nu$ be the generic point, then $k[\nu] = \mathcal{O}_{X,\nu} / \mathcal{m}_{\nu}$ where $\mathcal{m}_{\nu}$ is the maximal ideal corresponding to the generic point. 